# Failed to build pyarrow (for python 3.7) with an error message ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyarrow which use PEP 517

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, apache-beam, pyarrow

I am trying to install apache-beam[gcp] in my virtual env.

```
     My python version is 3.7
     My pip3 version is 20.0.2
```

when do try to install ( without sudo) and run the following:-

```
    pip3 install apache-beam[gcp]
```

I found a note from the pyarrow community regarding similar error for python 3.8 ( ARROW-7076) , but nothing for 3.7. I would greatly appreciate some help here as I am stuck!

Looks like this issue is open at the apache jira dashboard (AIRAVATA-3305)

```
  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRAVATA-3305? 
  jql=text%20~%20%22pip%20install%20python%203.7%22
```

Adding the full error message ( Now ran it as root, but got the same error message ):

```
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/io/hdfs.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/io
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/io/interfaces.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/io
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/io/memory.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/io
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/io/mman.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/io
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/io/slow.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/io
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/io/test_common.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/io
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/ipc
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/ipc/api.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/ipc
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/ipc/dictionary.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/ipc
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/ipc/feather.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/ipc
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/ipc/json_integration.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/ipc
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/ipc/json_simple.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/ipc
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/ipc/message.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/ipc
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/ipc/options.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/ipc
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/ipc/reader.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/ipc
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/ipc/test_common.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/ipc
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/ipc/util.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/ipc
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/ipc/writer.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/ipc
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/json
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/json/api.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/json
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/json/chunked_builder.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/json
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/json/chunker.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/json
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/json/converter.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/json
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/json/options.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/json
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/json/parser.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/json
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/json/rapidjson_defs.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/json
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/json/reader.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/json
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/json/test_common.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/json
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/python
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/python/api.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/python
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/python/arrow_to_pandas.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/python
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/python/benchmark.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/python
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/python/common.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/python
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/python/config.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/python
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/python/datetime.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/python
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/python/decimal.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/python
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/python/deserialize.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/python
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/python/extension_type.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/python
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/python/flight.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/python
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/python/helpers.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/python
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/python/inference.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/python
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/python/init.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/python
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/python/io.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/python
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/python/iterators.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/python
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/python/numpy_convert.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/python
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/python/numpy_interop.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/python
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/python/numpy_to_arrow.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/python
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/python/platform.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/python
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/python/pyarrow.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/python
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/python/pyarrow_api.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/python
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/python/pyarrow_lib.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/python
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/python/python_to_arrow.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/python
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/python/serialize.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/python
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/python/type_traits.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/python
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/python/visibility.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/python
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/testing
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/testing/extension_type.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/testing
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/testing/generator.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/testing
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/testing/gtest_common.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/testing
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/testing/gtest_util.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/testing
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/testing/random.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/testing
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/testing/util.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/testing
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/align_util.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/atomic_shared_ptr.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/base64.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/basic_decimal.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/bit_stream_utils.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/bit_util.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/bpacking.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/checked_cast.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/compare.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/compiler_util.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/compression.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/compression_brotli.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/compression_bz2.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/compression_lz4.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/compression_snappy.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/compression_zlib.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/compression_zstd.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/config.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/cpu_info.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/decimal.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/delimiting.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/double_conversion.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/formatting.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/functional.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/hash_util.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/hashing.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/int_util.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/io_util.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/iterator.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/key_value_metadata.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/logging.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/macros.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/make_unique.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/memory.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/neon_util.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/optional.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/parallel.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/parsing.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/print.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/range.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/rle_encoding.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/sort.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/sse_util.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/stopwatch.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/string.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/string_builder.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/string_view.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/task_group.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/thread_pool.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/time.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/trie.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/type_traits.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/ubsan.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/uri.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/utf8.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/variant.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/vector.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/visibility.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/util/windows_compatibility.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/util
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/vendored
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/vendored/datetime.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/vendored
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/vendored/optional.hpp -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/vendored
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/vendored/string_view.hpp -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/vendored
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/vendored/variant.hpp -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/vendored
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/vendored/xxhash.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/vendored
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/vendored/datetime
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/vendored/datetime/date.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/vendored/datetime
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/vendored/datetime/ios.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/vendored/datetime
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/vendored/datetime/tz.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/vendored/datetime
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/vendored/datetime/tz_private.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/vendored/datetime
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/vendored/datetime/visibility.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/vendored/datetime
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/vendored/double-conversion
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/vendored/double-conversion/bignum-dtoa.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/vendored/double-conversion
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/vendored/double-conversion/bignum.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/vendored/double-conversion
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/vendored/double-conversion/cached-powers.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/vendored/double-conversion
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/vendored/double-conversion/diy-fp.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/vendored/double-conversion
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/vendored/double-conversion/double-conversion.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/vendored/double-conversion
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/vendored/double-conversion/fast-dtoa.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/vendored/double-conversion
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/vendored/double-conversion/fixed-dtoa.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/vendored/double-conversion
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/vendored/double-conversion/ieee.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/vendored/double-conversion
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/vendored/double-conversion/strtod.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/vendored/double-conversion
  copying pyarrow/include/arrow/vendored/double-conversion/utils.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/include/arrow/vendored/double-conversion
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/includes
  copying pyarrow/includes/__init__.pxd -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/includes
  copying pyarrow/includes/common.pxd -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/includes
  copying pyarrow/includes/libarrow.pxd -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/includes
  copying pyarrow/includes/libarrow_cuda.pxd -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/includes
  copying pyarrow/includes/libarrow_dataset.pxd -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/includes
  copying pyarrow/includes/libarrow_flight.pxd -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/includes
  copying pyarrow/includes/libarrow_fs.pxd -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/includes
  copying pyarrow/includes/libgandiva.pxd -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/includes
  copying pyarrow/includes/libplasma.pxd -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/includes
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/tensorflow
  copying pyarrow/tensorflow/plasma_op.cc -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/tensorflow
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/tensorflow/plasma_op.so.dSYM
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/tensorflow/plasma_op.so.dSYM/Contents
  copying pyarrow/tensorflow/plasma_op.so.dSYM/Contents/Info.plist -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/tensorflow/plasma_op.so.dSYM/Contents
  copying pyarrow/tests/pyarrow_cython_example.pyx -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/tests
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/tests/data
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/tests/data/orc
  copying pyarrow/tests/data/orc/README.md -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/tests/data/orc
  copying pyarrow/tests/data/orc/TestOrcFile.emptyFile.jsn.gz -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/tests/data/orc
  copying pyarrow/tests/data/orc/TestOrcFile.emptyFile.orc -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/tests/data/orc
  copying pyarrow/tests/data/orc/TestOrcFile.test1.jsn.gz -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/tests/data/orc
  copying pyarrow/tests/data/orc/TestOrcFile.test1.orc -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/tests/data/orc
  copying pyarrow/tests/data/orc/TestOrcFile.testDate1900.jsn.gz -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/tests/data/orc
  copying pyarrow/tests/data/orc/TestOrcFile.testDate1900.orc -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/tests/data/orc
  copying pyarrow/tests/data/orc/decimal.jsn.gz -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/tests/data/orc
  copying pyarrow/tests/data/orc/decimal.orc -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/tests/data/orc
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/tests/data/parquet
  copying pyarrow/tests/data/parquet/v0.7.1.all-named-index.parquet -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/tests/data/parquet
  copying pyarrow/tests/data/parquet/v0.7.1.column-metadata-handling.parquet -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/tests/data/parquet
  copying pyarrow/tests/data/parquet/v0.7.1.parquet -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/tests/data/parquet
  copying pyarrow/tests/data/parquet/v0.7.1.some-named-index.parquet -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pyarrow/tests/data/parquet
  running build_ext
  creating /tmp/pip-install-jar_d6v5/pyarrow/build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6
  -- Running cmake for pyarrow
  cmake -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3  -DPYARROW_BUILD_CUDA=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_FLIGHT=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_GANDIVA=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_DATASET=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_ORC=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_PARQUET=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_PLASMA=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_S3=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_HDFS=off -DPYARROW_USE_TENSORFLOW=off -DPYARROW_BUNDLE_ARROW_CPP=off -DPYARROW_BUNDLE_BOOST=off -DPYARROW_GENERATE_COVERAGE=off -DPYARROW_BOOST_USE_SHARED=on -DPYARROW_PARQUET_USE_SHARED=on -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=release /tmp/pip-install-jar_d6v5/pyarrow
  error: command 'cmake' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyarrow
  Building wheel for google-apitools (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for google-apitools: filename=google_apitools-0.5.28-py3-none-any.whl size=131642 sha256=53006fe1611f352b29680065003fd0568a63aa046b676bd54bf3780743ffaedd
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/49/56/1c/73a513e437099b768ededdcb95106a58f5cdd048fb27ff640b
  Building wheel for docopt (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for docopt: filename=docopt-0.6.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl size=19852 sha256=99e8eed8943e34a2bf2457d3a6f7f269e95eafa9386d2f0766c32d881fb1df40
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/3f/2a/fa/4d7a888e69774d5e6e855d190a8a51b357d77cc05eb1c097c9
  Building wheel for grpc-google-iam-v1 (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for grpc-google-iam-v1: filename=grpc_google_iam_v1-0.12.3-py3-none-any.whl size=15434 sha256=bd5259daf0a66e2a34afac785bb7177d843166633433393cb1907740528f4b3f
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/76/65/cd/392da05e43270f143b6c5076ba88d39144abff586792593e7c
  Building wheel for googleapis-common-protos (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for googleapis-common-protos: filename=googleapis_common_protos-1.51.0-py3-none-any.whl size=74527 sha256=bb94fa9ac3db45115fd71380b4ca671c7d1074d75a9a8eb25e93148843ba63c9
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/35/8d/af/a922cb18800b31fadac3523cadf6c1efdf233b788fe7a4da70
Successfully built apache-beam crcmod dill fastavro future hdfs avro-python3 google-apitools docopt grpc-google-iam-v1 googleapis-common-protos
Failed to build pyarrow
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyarrow which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Comment: Can you share the non-truncated log of `pip install -vvv pyarrow`. This would in improving debugging / writing a more helpful answer.

Answer (score 3):

`pyarrow` is available as a `manylinux2010` for Python 3.7 and shouldn't require any compilation on Linux at all. There are two possible things that may prevent `pip` from picking up the `manylinux` wheel:

- Your `pip` version is too old to know about the new `manylinux` tag, try updating `pip` to the latest version.
- You are a user of Alpine Linux which uses a different `libc` implementation and thus doesn't support `manylinux` wheels by default.

You could also install the necessary requirements for compilation like `cmake`, `boost`, .. but this will be much complexer than figuring out why `pip` is not installing the respective wheels.

Comment: as you can see from above, the pip version is 20.0.2 which is the latest.

Comment: I am using aarch-linux on Nividia Nano.4.9.140-tegra Arch Linux64

Comment: added the max no of error messages the stackoverflow would permit me to add

Comment: @Uwe L. Korn, Could you provide your insight regarding installing pyarrow in python 3.7 in a windows machine?

Comment: @san What exactly? Maybe make a new question for this.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I managed to solve my installation issues. This is what I did:

1. Check out the apache-beam dependencies before installing it :
   https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-dependencies/
2. start your virtual env in conda ( I ran as user and not as root)

   ```
    (base) $ source activate <myenv>
   ```
3. I copied all of these dependency package info from the above  into a requirement.txt file as shown below:- ( cut and paste it)

   ```
   absl-py==0.9.0
   astor==0.8.1
   atomicwrites==1.3.0
   attrs==19.3.0
   avro-python3==1.8.2
   beautifulsoup4==4.8.1
   bs4==0.0.1
   cachetools==3.1.1
   certifi==2019.11.28
   chardet==3.0.4
   crcmod==1.7
   Cython==0.29.13
   dill==0.3.1.1
   docopt==0.6.2
   fastavro==0.21.24
   fasteners==0.15
   freezegun==0.3.12
   future==0.17.1
   gast==0.2.2
   google-api-core==1.16.0
   google-apitools==0.5.28
   google-auth==1.11.3
   google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.1
   google-cloud-bigquery==1.24.0
   google-cloud-bigtable==1.0.0
   google-cloud-core==1.1.0
   google-cloud-datastore==1.7.4
   google-cloud-dlp==0.13.0
   google-cloud-language==1.3.0
   google-cloud-pubsub==1.0.2
   google-cloud-spanner==1.13.0
   google-cloud-videointelligence==1.13.0
   google-cloud-vision==0.42.0
   google-pasta==0.2.0
   google-resumable-media==0.5.0
   googleapis-common-protos==1.51.0
   grpc-google-iam-v1==0.12.3
   grpcio==1.24.3
   grpcio-gcp==0.2.2
   guppy3==3.0.9
   h5py==2.10.0
   hdfs==2.5.8
   httplib2==0.12.0
   idna==2.9importlib-metadata==1.5.0
   joblib==0.14.1
   Keras-Applications==1.0.8
   Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.0
   Markdown==3.2.1
   mock==2.0.0
   monotonic==1.5
   more-itertools==8.2.0
   nltk==3.4.5
   nose==1.3.7
   nose-xunitmp==0.4.1
   numpy==1.17.3
   oauth2client==3.0.0
   oauthlib==3.1.0
   opt-einsum==3.2.0
   packaging==20.3
   pandas==0.25.2
   pbr==5.4.4
   Pillow==6.2.1
   pip==20.0.2
   pluggy==0.13.1
   protobuf==3.11.1
   protorpc==0.12.0
   py==1.8.1
   pyarrow==0.16.1
   pyasn1==0.4.8
   pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
   pydot==1.4.1
   pymongo==3.9.0
   pyparsing==2.4.6
   pytest==4.6.6
   python-dateutil==2.8.1
   python-gflags==3.1.2
   python-snappy==0.5.4
   pytz==2019.3
   PyYAML==3.13
   requests==2.23.0
   requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
   rsa==4.0
   scikit-learn==0.21.3
   scipy==1.4.1
   setuptools==46.0.0
   six==1.14.0
   soupsieve==2.0
   tensorboard==2.1.1
   tensorflow==2.1.0
   tensorflow-estimator==2.1.0
   termcolor==1.1.0
   typing-extensions==3.7.4.1
   urllib3==1.25.8
   wcwidth==0.1.8
   Werkzeug==1.0.0
   wheel==0.34.2
   wrapt==1.12.1
   zipp==3.1.0
   ```

   3. I had to use conda and pip installation interchangeably as some of these packages are into available with the respective repos:

      (myenv) $conda install --name myenv --yes --file requirements.txt

This will install what conda can find from its repos.  For pyarrow, conda was the only way out for me as I was not able to get the cmake build going with pip on my Nano arch linux 64 bit.

5. You can run the same using pip to install what may have failed using conda

   ```
    (myenv) $pip install -r requirements.txt
   ```
6. Now install apache-beam[gcp]:

   ```
   pip install apache-beam[gcp]==2.20.0
   ```

This may not be best way of instaling and I am merely noting the steps I took after many days of frustrating experience installing apache-beam.
I initially thought that running pip install apache-beam[gcp] would sort out the dependencies etc, but that was not the case. I must make a disclaimer that I have multiple virtual env on the same machine  and I had tried to install the apache-beam as a user and root, and therefore could have messed it up.

Probably these steps would also work in other linux env as well.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you can't use `sudo pip3 install apache-beam[gcp]`? That worked perfectly when I tried to replicate this issue. Generally speaking, this issue arises when a package that uses PEP 517 prevents you from building it from the source. Using a root shell sidesteps all these issues.

Alternatively, there is always downloading the source and building it yourself.

Comment: I don't want to install beam at the root level and keep it local to my development env.